# Identify Vintage Power Cord for 1980s Organ

Tags: power, ac, identification, input, vintage

[image][image]I Recently acquired a Technics SX-C600 organ but it needs a power cord. Does anyone know what type of power cord I should get for this?
My understanding is that this is a rare organ.

Comment: How about this: https://www.amazon.com/Hosa-PWC-178-NEMA-1-15P-Power/dp/B000068OA6 ? BTW, takes like 2 seconds to google "rectangular power cord".

Comment: Check (and post) the dimensions though.. Also you might want to find out what is the voltage it is operating from.

Comment: That looks easy enough to replace with a newer "clover leaf" or figure 8 plug and socket...

Answer (score 11):

I'm reasonably certain you need an IEC 60320 C9 plug to mate with that connector.

Wikipedia has this to say: "This kind of coupler is used by Roland Corporation for a couple of synthesizer and drum computer models (for example: TR-909) and by Revox for many older models of their HiFi equipment (for example, A76, A77, A78, B77, B225). Was also used heavily on Marantz Hifi equipment in the 1980s and 1990s." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320))

[image]